# Bootstrap Magento in external script with a second database connection

Tags: magento-1, script, external

I use below code to bootstrap Magento in an external script, which works. As an example it gets the name of a specific product.

**Is it possible to connect to another Magento database (on the same server) from such a script? If yes, how would I do this?** I tried several things but didn't got a working end result.

```
<?php

require_once '../app/Mage.php';
Mage::app();

$sku = 'product X';
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku', $sku);

var_dump($product->getName());
```

Answer (score 0):

This is achievable. You need to define database credentials in your local.xml where you have your script placed. You can have something like below:

[image]

Once you have some create a module / model to connect to second database and play around it to achieve what you want.

Comment: Thanks. I just want to use Magento default models. For example get a product with 'catalog/product' model from the second database. How would I do that? Can you give an example?